# Spring set default Content-type to "application/json;charset=utf-8" when Jackson is not used

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to change my spring app default "Content-type" to "application/json;charset=utf-8" instead of only "application/json"

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that? The default encoding for JSON is UTF-8.

Comment: I'm not using Jackson. My controllers are returning ResponseEntity<String>, so "application/text" by default.

Answer (score 5):

Spring > 4.3.4

```
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

Comment: This is deprecated from > Spring 5.2

Answer (score 4):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(
         ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        final Map<String, String> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameterMap.put("charset", "utf-8");

        configurer.defaultContentType(new MediaType(
          MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, parameterMap));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, Collections.singletonMap("charset", "utf-8")) or new MediaType("application", "json" , Charset.forName("utf-8")). In new Spring there is MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8

Comment: Also in Spring 4.3+ you can do `new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution for default content type charset, that I found, by using a request filter:

```java
@Component
public class CharsetRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify produces

for example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json; charset=utf-8" })

public @ResponseBody Object get1() {
...
}
```