# How to make spring boot default to application/json;charset=utf-8 instead of application/json;charset=iso-8859-1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I am updating spring-boot from 1.3.6 to 2.1.3 and while before responses had content type `application/json;charset=UTF-8`, now I am getting a charset of iso-8859-1.

I would like to have utf 8.

My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value={"/myService/{serviceId}"}, method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> handlePostServiceId(final InputStream requestInputStream,
            @PathVariable String serviceId,
            final HttpServletRequest servletRequest,) {
       <$businessLogic>
       return new ResponseEntity<>(new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

I can get it to return utf-8 if I include `produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` in my `@RequestMapping` but I would like to only have to set that once, rather than for every single API.

I also tried adding

```
@Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(
         ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
         configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
    }
```

to my WebMvcConfigurer as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275291/2855921  but that broke my availability api which consumes plain/text content type.

I also ensured that my request was UTF-8, so it is not just mirroring back the format I gave.

Any ideas on how I can set the charset to be UTF-8 for the entire project?

Comment: You can set `produces` at class level which will get applied to all the api's in that controller class.

Comment: I really don't know what happened. It turns out it was just two mappings that didn't work properly. I tried both the application.properties method as well as using a CharacterEncodingFilter, but neither fixed the issue. 

The two offending mappings were the only ones which explicitly says produces, but they were set to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE which is just "application/json", and trying that in other mappings gave back utf-8. 

I ended up just setting those two to MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE manually and moving on, as nothing else worked.

Comment: Someone may have a different issue and find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054648/how-to-configure-characterencodingfilter-in-springboot

Comment: Did you find a way

Comment: @Mohit see my answer

Comment: It's unclear if this was solved, but if you were reading from a messages.properties-file like me, this may fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114437/483113

Answer (score 21):

Add the below properties to the *application.properties* file:

For **Spring Boot 1.x**

```
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" 
# header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
# Enable http encoding support.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
# Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

For **Spring Boot 2.x**

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force-response=true
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server.servlet.encoding.charset

Comment: I tried adding that but am still getting iso-8859-1

Comment: While running your spring boot application add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to java command line agrs.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using default object mapper (`Jackson`) then the encoding can be forced with this simple configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jsonConverter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return jsonConverter;
    }
```

Here the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()` constructor uses public `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` class to set default parameters for an object mapper.

For another object mapper (`Gson` or `Jsonb`) you can look into `AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter()` constructor.

Note also `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8` was deprecated in favor of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` since Spring 5.2.
So in tests I prefer to use `contentTypeCompatibleWith(...)` instead of `contentType(..._UTF8)`:

```
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/resource"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                // .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn();
```

Links:

- Commit where `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8` was replaced by `APPLICATION_JSON` in `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` — https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c38542739734c15e84a28ecc5f575127f25d310a
- Chromium issue discussing `"Content-Type: application/json"` support —https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438464
- No `"charset"` for `"Content-Type: application/json"` in RFC7159 — https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-11

More examples with `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`:

- Customizing HttpMessageConverters with Spring Boot and Spring MVC — https://dzone.com/articles/customizing
- Http Message Converters with the Spring Framework — https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

Comment: It doesn’t work for me. In my case, everything is working fine for English characters. But if I try to send some french or Spanish characters then it's throwing an error

Comment: @DeepakKumar It's unclear if this was solved for you, but if you were reading from a messages.properties-file like me, this may fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28114437/483113