# How to allow French character in Spring Rest JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, character-encoding

I have created a rest API using Spring boot. I am using JSON as the request and response type. Everything was working fine and I was happy until I tested it will some french words.
I want my API to support all languages characters as this application might be used work wide.
My JSON looks like below:

```
{
    "highlights": "Adiós",
    "language": "FR",
    "longDescription": "Adiós",
    "name": "Adiós",
    "shortDescription": "Adiós"
}
```

Spring is throwing the below error:

```
JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x73; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x73\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 25]
```

I am using **Java 11** with **Spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE**

**Edit:**

I even tried sending Content-type as `application/json; charset=utf-8` and adding same in `@PostMapping` consume and produce. But nothing helped.

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comment I also tried setting below spring property But still didn't work.

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force-response=true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make spring boot default to application/json;charset=utf-8 instead of application/json;charset=iso-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640629/how-to-make-spring-boot-default-to-application-jsoncharset-utf-8-instead-of-app)

Comment: It doesn't matter but it looks more like Spanish than French. Unlikely it causes the error, though.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for comment but I have tried this also but still I am getting the same error msg

Comment: @YuriKhristich I am not sure what language is this word, But I just want my API to support all the language. It does include Spanish and French

Comment: @DeepakKumar In this case, I would suggest [edit]ing the question and adding this information. I will retract my vote.

Comment: Ensure that your _JSON_ is saved using `utf-8` encoding. Open the file in _Notepad++_; I'm pretty sure that its _encoding-fu_ will detect "_ANSI_".

Comment: This link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/json-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Comment: @JosefZ I am not reading JSON from the file. I am sending it through API call